# Where does Putty store known_hosts information on Windows?

Tags: windows, ssh, putty, known-hosts

How do I tell if Putty already knows about and has cached credentials for specific ssh servers?

Another way to ask this question is what is the Windows/Putty equivalent of a unix/ssh known_hosts file?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33240137/10245

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Putty stores known hosts under a registry key:  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SoftWare\SimonTatham\PuTTY\SshHostKeys`.

Comment: In my case, the path was different. However, just search for the registry key(s) "SshHostKeys"

Answer (score 10):

So in windows known_hosts for PuTTY is SshHostKeys.

that is stored at the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\SshHostKeys` location. To reach that location, the `Registry Editor` supposed to be used.

- go to start - look for `regedit`
- then you will see all the directories on the left pane under computer
- just like this image says go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\SshHostKeys` location - [location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K59kf.png)
- then you can modify like you wish [Known host options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJ9Sc.png)
- If needed you can check the content in the `SshHostKeys` file using this command `REG QUERY HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\SshHostKeys` in PowerShell

And then the cache will be cleared. Will be everything new again for that particular entry

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned before Putty stores SSH host keys in registry `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\SshHostKeys]`.

I've written about how to copy SSH host keys between different users/machines here http://isbyr.com/copy-putty-ssh-hosts-keys-different-usersmachines-windows/